# ArcGIS JS API 4.x - Polyline size(extrusion) in 3D View

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've a PolyLine , I need to adjust its height and display it in `SceneView` (As a paper with 0 thickness) . I was able to display the PolyLine as a Line and I could be able to adjust its elevation (relative-to-ground) , but I couldn't control the `visualVariables.size` , Is there any special symbology - renderer I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Well , I found a workaround solution , the idea is to duplicate the coordinates and add a very tiny buffer .

`var clonedArray = geometry.coordinates.slice(0);
var newClonedArray = new Array();
for (k = 0; k < clonedArray.length; k++) {
    newClonedArray[k] = new Array();
    for (l = 0; l < clonedArray[k].length; l++) {
        newClonedArray[k][l] = clonedArray[k][l] + 0.01;
    }
}
var newReversedClonedArray = newClonedArray.reverse();
fakePolygon = clonedArray.concat(newReversedClonedArray);`